# Compiling Play! framework on Mac OS Leopard with pre-installed "ant"

Tags: macos, ant, playframework

When I start "ant" Play! framework I get this errors:
What am I doing wrong?

```
iMac-ale:framework alliku$ ant
Buildfile: /Users/alliku/Documents/temp/play/play/framework/build.xml

clean:

clean-unittest:

version:
     [echo] Version master-61d6b44

compile:
    [mkdir] Created dir: /Users/alliku/Documents/temp/play/play/framework/classes
    [javac] /Users/alliku/Documents/temp/play/play/framework/build.xml:67: warning: 'includeantruntime' was not set, defaulting to build.sysclasspath=last; set to false for repeatable builds
    [javac] Compiling 254 source files to /Users/alliku/Documents/temp/play/play/framework/classes
    [javac] /Users/alliku/Documents/temp/play/play/framework/src/play/libs/F.java:644: play.libs.F.None is already defined in play.libs.F
    [javac]     public static None<Object> None = new None<Object>();
    [javac]                                ^
    [javac] /Users/alliku/Documents/temp/play/play/framework/src/play/libs/XML.java:12: package javax.xml.crypto does not exist
    [javac] import javax.xml.crypto.KeySelector;
    [javac]                         ^
    [javac] /Users/alliku/Documents/temp/play/play/framework/src/play/libs/XML.java:13: package javax.xml.crypto.dsig does not exist
    [javac] import javax.xml.crypto.dsig.CanonicalizationMethod;
    [javac]                              ^
    [javac] /Users/alliku/Documents/temp/play/play/framework/src/play/libs/XML.java:14: package javax.xml.crypto.dsig does not exist
    [javac] import javax.xml.crypto.dsig.DigestMethod;
    [javac]                              ^
    [javac] /Users/alliku/Documents/temp/play/play/framework/src/play/libs/XML.java:15: package javax.xml.crypto.dsig does not exist
    [javac] import javax.xml.crypto.dsig.Reference;
    [javac]                              ^
    [javac] /Users/alliku/Documents/temp/play/play/framework/src/play/libs/XML.java:16: package javax.xml.crypto.dsig does not exist
    [javac] import javax.xml.crypto.dsig.SignatureMethod;
    [javac]                              ^
    [javac] /Users/alliku/Documents/temp/play/play/framework/src/play/libs/XML.java:17: package javax.xml.crypto.dsig does not exist
```

etc....

Comment: Needed Java 1.6. Close question

Answer (score 2):

Answered by author. Java 6 is required.